# Probability of getting a full house in five-card poker with 4 cards added?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, poker

a)  If I draw 5 cards randomly what are the chances of getting a full house ?

b) Which other card can you remove to maximize your chances of getting full house?

So you have in total 56 cards, the 4 added cards are a new king for each type. I do not really know how to do this.

Comment: So instead of $4$ kings, we have $8$ kings in the $56$ card pack here? Also does full house mean exactly $3$ cards of one rank and $2$ of another rank?

Comment: yes we have 8 kings in total, do not really know exactly what you mean there in the end.

Comment: 3 cards of the same, and 2 of the same

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $56$ cards with $8$ kings and rest $48$ cards are of $12$ ranks similar to a standard $52$ cards pack.

a) Possibility $1$ for getting a full house -

We have two ranks without king -

So we first select which two ranks from: $1$ to $10$ and $J, Q, A$ and then any of the chosen two can be $3$ cards and the other $2$. That is,

$2 \cdot {12 \choose 2} {4 \choose 3} {4 \choose 2}$ possibilities

b) Possibility $2$ for getting a full house -

One of the ranks is king and so we choose $1$ rank from remaining $12$ ranks. Then we either have $3$ cards of king and $2$ of the other or $2$ cards of king and $3$ of the other. That is,

${12 \choose 1} \big[{8 \choose 3} {4 \choose 2} + {8 \choose 2} {4 \choose 3})\big]$ possibilities.

Total count of favorable possibilities is sum of $(a)$ and $(b)$ and then to find desired probability, we divide by

c) Total possibilities without restrictions, which is ${56 \choose 5}$.

Comment: Okay, thanks a lot. I think I understand completely.

Comment: You are welcome!